# Can I extend a command adding my own aliases?

Tags: command, alias

I created a few aliases to work with `nodejs` projects such as:

```
alias lsc="cat package.json | jq '.scripts'"
```

to list all the available commands in the `scripts` portion of the `package.json` file

Ideally I would like to run this as `npm scripts` or `npm something` but `npm` is an existing executable program in my path.

Is it possible to extend this to add my own aliases?

Comment: You don't need an extra process to pipe a file to another, this is sometimes called [useless use of cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat). The shell can do it `<package.json jq '.scripts'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disclaimer: I know *nothing* about Node.js or `npm`.

Use a shell function that overrides the `npm` command:

```sh
npm () {
    if [ "$1" = scripts ]; then
        jq '.scripts' package.json
    else
        command npm "$@"
    fi
}
```

This shell function detects if the function's first argument is the string `scripts` or not.  If it is, it runs your `jq` command.  If it isn't, it calls the real `npm` command with the original command line arguments.

The `command` utility makes sure that the *function* isn't called (would create an infinite recursion otherwise).

The code above could be placed wherever you define ordinary aliases.

If `npm` *already is* a shell function, this would fail to do the correct thing.

---

Extending this to a number of new sub-commands, the `if`-`then`-`elif` code would be messy.  Instead:

```sh
npm () {
    case $1 in
        scripts)  jq '.scripts' package.json ;;
        hummus)   hummus-command ;;
        cinnamon) spice-command ;;
        baubles)  stuff ;;
        *) command npm "$@"
    esac
}
```

This would create `scripts`, `hummus`, `cinnamon` and `baubles` sub-commands that would call other commands.  If the first argument of the function doesn't match any of the custom sub-commands, the real `npm` command is called as before.

Note that adding an alternative for an *existing* `npm` sub-command would override that sub-command for `npm`.  If you want to call that *real* sub-command from your own alternative sub-command, call `command npm "$@"` (assuming you haven't called `shift` to shift off the sub-command name, in which case you want to call `command npm sub-command "$@"` instead).

Each new sub-command would have access to the command line arguments of the function, but you might want to `shift` the sub-command's name off the list:

```
npm () {
    case $1 in
        scripts)  jq '.scripts' package.json ;;
        hummus)
            shift
            echo '"npm hummus" was called with these additional arguments:'
            printf '%s\n' "$@"
            ;;
        *) command npm "$@"
    esac
}
```

Example of that last function running:

```
$ npm hummus "hello world" {1..3}
"npm hummus" was called with these additional arguments:
hello world
1
2
3
```

Comment: This answer was perfect. Thank you! And props for teaching me a better way to use jq